# How different is the Millennium Falcon in the official trailer vs. Episode VI?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, millennium-falcon

What are the differences between Millennium Falcon as depicted in the latest trailer (October 2015) of Episode VII and that of Episode VI?

Comment: P.S. I made up Episode VII tag, within 25 char limit. If someone feels like a better tag name is warranted, have at it.

Comment: How about just [the-force-awakens]? Also, [spaceship] tag?

Comment: We do already have [tag:the-force-awakens] (cc. @randal'thor)

Comment: How do we know it's even the same ship. It's probably an upgraded model. MF-1701-C.

Comment: @MrLister - because Han wouldn't fly anything else.

Comment: I'd like to note that in the film there's actually quite a bit of discussion of the in-universe mechanical modifications that have been applied to the Falcon before TFA begins. It's all technobabble, but it still emphasizes the changes over the years (and, very loudly, Solo's concern for his ship)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer uses information from all the trailers and teasers. Hopefully, you won't mind.

From the article, [Star Wars Episode 7: What’s happened to the Millennium Falcon by the time of The Force Awakens?](http://metro.co.uk/2015/08/11/star-wars-episode-7-whats-happened-to-the-millennium-falcon-by-the-time-of-the-force-awakens-5333389/)

The Interior:

> Early photographs leaked from the set showed the Falcon with a very different decor inside.
>   Instead of the utilitarian and somewhat spartan designs inside, the modern ship boasted plush brown leather seats and wall padding. It very much looks like someone has finally given the fastest hunk of junk in the galaxy the TLC it always deserved.

[image]

The Exterior:

> As mentioned, the Falcon lost her top of the line sensor dish at the end of Jedi. Solo wouldn’t have been impressed as that cost him a lot of credits and had the capability to detect Imperial ships long before they were aware of him.
>   Until the announcement of the sequel trilogy we thought the Imperial threat was largely over, but as we are learning, the Empire persisted and still survives as the First Order by the time The Force Awakens starts.
>   Now the Falcon has a different sensor dish, one much more like the primary sensor array carried on top of Blockade Runners (the first ship we see fleeing a Star Destroyer at the start of Star Wars back in 1977). If that’s the case, the Falcon has maintained her all-important tactical advantage.

[image]

Comment: **Why does it look like Chewbacca had a face lift?**

Comment: @wadcheber I wouldn't be surprised. He is pushing 300.

Comment: He was already 200 at the Battle of Yavin.  Another couple of decades shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I think Chewie has botox.

Comment: Clearly, Chewie is the Wookiee Merlin, he ages backwards. He can remember the future, so he knows what you'll be doing in it. His seemingly incoherent roaring is actually English spoken backwards and at right angles to our normal spacetime dimensions, and he's been trying to warn us about the rise of Darth Jar-Jar in Episode 9 all along.

Comment: Where does the top image come from? It doesn't look like anything from the Original Trilogy.

Comment: @tuttifruittijacuzzi The top image is from one of the new teasers.

Comment: Re: "all trailers": I don't mind at all and greatly appreciate extra info. I merely assumed that latest trailer would have 100% of info from previous ones, perhaps incorrectly

Comment: @WadCheber: That's not how ageing works. Some humans go from relatively youthful to grey and saggy in a matter of 2-3 years (and let's say that's the human equivalent of a Wookie's 20-30 years). It really depends what you're doing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Actually, that is how aging *usually* works.  Once you're an adult, sexually mature, you don't age as quickly in a visible sense unless you're seriously abusing your body.  The difference between 2 years old and 7 years old is usually much more noticeable than the difference between 30 and 50, even though the former is 1/4 of the latter.  Not to mention the fact that our aging process would be far less dramatic if we were entirely covered in hair.

Comment: If we assume that the average human lifespan in this galaxy is about 80 years old, and compare it to a Wookiee's 400 year lifespan, then 5 human years = 1 Wookiee year.  At 200 years old, Chewie is literally middle aged, and the difference between episode 6 and 7 is like a human going from 40 years old to 46 years old.  Not a big change, in most cases.

Comment: @WadCheber: Yes, but the same thing happens towards the end of the life cycle, especially when you are in a stressful line of work. Compare Obama in 2008 to Obama now. At a certain point in time, you can visibly age quite quickly. It's not a completely linear thing. The idea that Chewie can't possibly have visibly aged in a couple of decades just because he lives for a few hundred years is ludicrous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The idea that a walking carpet drastically  changes over 5% of its lifespan in the middle of said lifespan is ridiculous.

Comment: Okay then you know best mate

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement @RogueJedi's excellent answer, we now know a bit more from the film and Alan Dean Foster's official novelization:

- **New compressor**

  > Moving slightly to his right, he touched a couple of contacts and was rewarded with a readout that was anything but pleasing.
  >   **“Hey! Some moof-milker installed a compressor on the ignition line!”**

  (spoiler: Han didn't think it was a good idea and Ray agreed)